# Find a File By Owner In Linux

Tags: linux, unix, find

I need to find a file belonging to a specific user.
I have tried using -O "userName" but, it prints: The -O option must be immediately followed by a decimal integer. I tried it with small 'o' and still, it wouldn't work

Comment: The way to search through manpages is with `/the_search_regex`.

Comment: Also see [`find(1)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find).

Answer (score 1):

For searches based on the file owner, you should use the `-user` option.

```
find /path/to/some/folder -user exampleuser
```

The `-O` option is used for search optimization and is followed by an integer (1 to 3 levels).